# Existing tag with the name as my desired one, but for different thing

Tags: support, tags, ambiguous-tags

I want to ask a question in SO, about the deployment automation platform **[glu](https://github.com/linkedin/glu)**. There are however no questions about it (only a mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6451610/1047448)), and there is already a tag [glu](/questions/tagged/glu) for OpenGL GLU.

How should I tag my question?

**Edit**: Mat created tag [linkedin-glu](/questions/tagged/linkedin-glu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should post your question, without the [glu](/questions/tagged/glu) tag, but with whatever else is relevant, making clear what `glu` you're talking about, and add a comment asking for a new tag to be created.

I'd suggest [linkedin-glu](/questions/tagged/linkedin-glu), since that piece of software appears to come from [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/).

Once that's done, you can go ahead and propose a great little tag wiki for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can tag your question with the existing tags, starting from the tag for the programming language.
If there are enough questions about the same topic, then a tag like [linkedin-glu](/questions/tagged/linkedin-glu) could be created. Remember that a tag used from just a question is going to be automatically deleted, and a tag that applies to just 2-3 questions is not that much helpful.